# Error Displaying product page after migration and switching theme

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, theme, template, product-list

We are moving our site to a new theme and are testing it on a dev server.  When accessing a product listing page, we get the below error.  It happens with all product types.  Is there a core file that could have gotten corrupted during the switch over that needs to be replaced?

Running v 1.7.0.2

There has been an error processing your request

```
Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Simple::displayProductStockStatus(Array
(
)
)

Trace:
0 /home/admin/sites/larpexchange.com/app/design/frontend/flatastic/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml(34): Varien_Object->__call('displayProductS...', Array)

1 /home/admin/sites/larpexchange.com/app/design/frontend/flatastic/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml(34): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Simple->displayProductStockStatus()

2 /home/admin/sites/larpexchange.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/admin/sit...')

3 /home/admin/sites/larpexchange.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/flatas...')

4 /home/admin/sites/larpexchange.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()

5 /home/admin/sites/larpexchange.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()

6 /home/admin/sites/larpexchange.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()

7 /home/admin/sites/larpexchange.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('product_type_da...', true)

8 /home/admin/sites/larpexchange.com/app/design/frontend/flatastic/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml(76): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('product_type_da...')

9 /home/admin/sites/larpexchange.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/admin/sit...')

10 /home/admin/sites/larpexchange.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/flatas...')

11 /home/admin/sites/larpexchange.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()

12 /home/admin/sites/larpexchange.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()

13 /home/admin/sites/larpexchange.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()

14 /home/admin/sites/larpexchange.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()

15 /home/admin/sites/larpexchange.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()

16 /home/admin/sites/larpexchange.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)

17 /home/admin/sites/larpexchange.com/app/design/frontend/flatastic/default/template/page/1column.phtml(54): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')

18 /home/admin/sites/larpexchange.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/admin/sit...')

19 /home/admin/sites/larpexchange.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/flatas...')

20 /home/admin/sites/larpexchange.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()

21 /home/admin/sites/larpexchange.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()

22 /home/admin/sites/larpexchange.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()

23 /home/admin/sites/larpexchange.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()

24 /home/admin/sites/larpexchange.com/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(91): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()

25 /home/admin/sites/larpexchange.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Cms_IndexController->defaultNoRouteAction()

26 /home/admin/sites/larpexchange.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('defaultNoRoute')

27 /home/admin/sites/larpexchange.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): 
Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
28 /home/admin/sites/larpexchange.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
29 /home/admin/sites/larpexchange.com/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
30 /home/admin/sites/larpexchange.com/index.php(87): Mage::run('base', 'website')
31 {main
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a third party theme

Answer (score 1):

Well it looks like that function is not available in Magento 1.7 it seems that this function is in Magento 1.9 but I am not sure if it is in Magento 1.8 either.

If this is a bought template then I would suggest contacting the provider directly for support.